# Solve N^2 nonlinear equations system

Tags: python, equation-solving

I am trying to solve a system of N*N nonlinear equations, but I get stuck and do not understand what is the problem.

My equations are :

```
h_{j,i} = (T/2) \sum_{k=1..N}{f(h_{k,j})} - (T/2) f(h_{i,j})
```

for i and j in [1..N]^2, and where the h are the unknowns, f is a known function and T is a parameter.

In all the examples I have found, there are maybe two or three equations/unknowns, so one can implement the equations directly. Nevertheless, I have too many equations here, and I do not understand how to implement a code without explicitly writing all the equations, and using fsolve (on python).

Thanks for your help

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's math question, not programming

Comment: It is a programming question; I just don't understand how to generalize a 3-unknown solving on python

Comment: Maybe fsolve is the wrong tool? I think it would help if you expand your code snipped into an example. Including also input parameter and possible debug values.